# TypeError: gcd is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

My lib/gcd.js

```
function gcd(a, b) {
    if (!a) return b;
    if (!b) return a;

    while (1) {
      a%= b;
      if (!a) return b;
      b%= a;
      if (!b) return a;
    }
}

module.exports = gcd;
```

My test/gcd.test.js

```
const { gcd } = require("../lib");

describe("gcd", () => {
  test("Basic: gcd of 54 and 24 is 6", () => {
    expect(gcd(54, 24)).toBe(6);
  });

  test("Large Numbers: gcd of 123456 and 9876 is 12", () => {
    expect(gcd(123456, 9876)).toBe(12);
  });

  test("1 Negative: gcd of 54 and -24 is 6", () => {
    expect(gcd(54, -24)).toBe(6);
  });

  test("2 Negative: gcd of -54 and -24 is 6", () => {
    expect(gcd(-54, -24)).toBe(6);
  });

  test("gcd of 0 and 1 should throw error", () => {
    expect(() => {
      gcd(0, 1);
    }).toThrow();
  });
});
```

When I run the test using jest am getting this error saying:
TypeError: gcd is not a function

Can I know what is going wrong, is it anything related to the gcd function ?

Comment: Is it not `require("../lib/gcd.js")`?

Comment: What’s in lib/index.js? (`const gcd = require('../lib/gcd');` as PhuNgo mentioned would be even better, though.)

Comment: @Ryan I swear how did I miss that out !! Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

It should be this way:

```
const gcd = require("../lib/gcd.js");

describe("gcd", () => {
  test("Basic: gcd of 54 and 24 is 6", () => {
    expect(gcd(54, 24)).toBe(6);
  });

  test("Large Numbers: gcd of 123456 and 9876 is 12", () => {
    expect(gcd(123456, 9876)).toBe(12);
  });

  test("1 Negative: gcd of 54 and -24 is 6", () => {
    expect(gcd(54, -24)).toBe(6);
  });

  test("2 Negative: gcd of -54 and -24 is 6", () => {
    expect(gcd(-54, -24)).toBe(6);
  });

  test("gcd of 0 and 1 should throw error", () => {
    expect(() => {
      gcd(0, 1);
    }).toThrow();
  });
});
```